# _tkinter.TclError: character U+1f40d is above the range (U+0000-U+FFFF) allowed by Tcl

Tags: python, twitter, tkinter, tweepy

So I have this code which has been posting tweets just fine up until now...

```
public_tweets = api.home_timeline()

for tweet in public_tweets:

    name = ('\nTweet by: @' + tweet.user.screen_name)
    ID = ('\nID: @' + str(tweet.user.id)+ '\n')

    tweet = (tweet.text)
    space = ("\n\n")

    TwitterText.insert(END,name+ID+tweet+space)
```

But for some reason this error keeps appearing now:
_tkinter.TclError: character U+1f40d is above the range (U+0000-U+FFFF) allowed by Tcl

I understand that this has something to do with some characters not being able to be shown in Tkinter but is there any way to fix this???

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46173519/tkinter-tclerror-character-u1f449-is-above-the-range-u0000-uffff-allowed-b

Comment: I tried that but all it said was TypeError: object of type 'Status' has no len()