# How can I solve " character U+1f604 is above the range (U+0000-U+FFFF) allowed by Tcl" error problem in Spyder?

Tags: spyder

```
import spectral as spy
namedEnt =nltk.ne_chunk(tagged_words)
namedEnt.draw()
spy.ImageView
dir(spy)
```

In My variable explorer showed the parts of speech of every word but when I trying to execute this code to show the NLTK image there has occured an error

> > > >
> > >       character U+1f604 is above the range (U+0000-U+FFFF) allowed by Tcl

Please help me how can i solve it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [tkinter.TclError: character U+1f449 is above the range (U+0000-U+FFFF) allowed by Tcl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46173519/tkinter-tclerror-character-u1f449-is-above-the-range-u0000-uffff-allowed-b)